# Создание объекта в другом домене

Tags: c#, marshal

Изучаю C# по книге Рихтера и застопорился на создании объекта в соседнем домене. Копипаст кода из книги не выполняется. Вот пример без лишней мишуры:

```
public class myMarshallableClass : MarshalByRefObject { }

static void Main()
{
AppDomain d = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Second domain");
myMarshallableClass o = (myMarshallableClass)d.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName, "myMarshallableClass");
}
```

При попытке сздания объекта выкидывает System.TypeLoadException: "Не удалось загрузить тип "myMarshallableClass" из сборки "MyConsoleApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"."
Мол не может загрузить тип из основной сборки.. Видимо я что-то делаю не так...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.createinstanceandunwrap?view=net-5.0#System_AppDomain_CreateInstanceAndUnwrap_System_String_System_String_) вам нужно указывать Fully Qualified Name, т.е. укаваться namespace, а также если класс вложен в другой класс.

> The fully qualified name of the requested type, including the namespace but not the assembly, as returned by the FullName property.

Например:

```cs
AppDomain d = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Second domain");
myMarshallableClass o = (myMarshallableClass)d.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName, "MyConsoleApp.myMarshallableClass");
```

Должно работать, если у вас класс `myMarshallableClass` лежит в пространстве имен `MyConsoleApp`.

Код приведенный в книге будет работать, если вы не поместите его в namespace, просто создадите на самом "верхнем уровне" файла.